# After LatexCompiling with \ll the file /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex is displayed instead of the source tex file

Tags: compiling, vim-latex

Upon compiling a large Latex file with "\ll" inside Vim that contains on purpose an latex command typo  (using $\relta$ instead of $\Delta$)  I get 3 windows  (with the Vim look and feel -- i.e. no pop-up windows) of which the upper one no longer contains the source latex file but

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
```

whereas the second one contains a quickfix error list and the third an extract of the `.log`-file related with the selected entry of the error list as expected.
Obviously I wanted to see and access the source file in the first window and I don't understand why it disappeared and don't know how to get it back. The error itself was correctedly identified as "Undefined control sequence". But this is no the problem. I introduced this error on purpose. The problem is that at the end the source file is no longer displayed, so I would not be able to fix the typo.
So it is not a compiling problem, it is a display problem.

All errors respectively warnings in the quickfix error list are preceded by `/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`

In case there is no error in the latex source file, the source file stays visible in the first window.

Actually if I use a simpler file (10 lines, but of course of little interest) also containing a simple error, the problem does not occur neither.

Actually, the file that I compile is around 50pages long. So I will not post it here.

What goes wrong with this compiling process? I admit my knowledge on quickfix is still very very limited and would appreciate quick help.  Thank you

Comment: your question is impossible to understand, please edit it to show what input you made and what error you got. `\ll` is not an error it is a standard latex command unrelated to pgf. Any "windows" that you get will be a feature of your editor not of latex, but you have not said what editor your are using. LaTEx itself has no winow interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with vim-latex tracing the error to the wrong place and trying to take you to the right place to fix you (as would be helpful if you compile `foo.tex` which has `\input{bar.tex}` with the error being in `bar.tex`).

Setting `:let g:Tex_GotoError=0` keeps the cursor where it is after compilation but this also means you aren't moved to the right place for errors within the same file.
Personally I come across this issue sufficiently rarely I'm happy switching buffers (`<C-^>`) or navigating back with `:e /path/to/file`.

Really this is a bug in vim-latex, but I'm also not sure what exactly triggers it, I can't see a relevant open or closed issue in https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues and it may be a limit of what TeX logs rather than how vim-latex processes the information.